# Who are the Marvel characters in the "Clementoni 39411 - Impossible Puzzle - Marvel - 1000 Pieces" Jigsaw?

Tags: marvel, character-identification

Who are the Marvel heroes, villains and other assorted characters in the [Clementoni 39411 - Impossible Puzzle - Marvel - 1000 Pieces](https://www.clementoni.com/en/39411-marvel-1000-pcs-impossible-puzzle/) Jigsaw?

[image: Lots of Marvel Heroes]

Comment: Slightly bigger version here; https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/A1C5SnKvXNL.jpg

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that the incredibly hulking guy in the middle is Professor Angryman.

Comment: @Valorum nah... I'm sure that's just the Vision on steroids ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

1. [The Absorbing Man](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Carl_Creel_(Earth-616))
2. [The Green Goblin](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Norman_Osborn_(Earth-616))
3. [Thunderball](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Eliot_Franklin_(Thunderball)_(Earth-616))
4. [The Wrecker](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Dirk_Garthwaite_(Earth-616))
5. [Piledriver](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Brian_Calusky_(Earth-616))
6. [Bulldozer](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Henry_Camp_(Earth-616))
7. [Arnim Zola](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Arnim_Zola_(Earth-616))
8. [The Purple Man](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Zebediah_Killgrave_(Earth-616))
9. [Blade](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Eric_Brooks_(Earth-616))
10. [War Machine](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/James_Rhodes_(Earth-616))
11. [Hydra agent](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Hydra_(Earth-616))
12. [Venom (Eddie Brock)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Edward_Brock_(Earth-616))
13. [M.O.D.O.K.](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/George_Tarleton_(Earth-616))
14. [Devil Dinosaur](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Devil_Dinosaur_(Earth-78411))
15. [Nova (Sam Alexander)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Samuel_Alexander_(Earth-616))
16. [Ego the Living Planet](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Egros_(Earth-616))
17. [Baron Zemo](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Helmut_Zemo_(Earth-616))
18. [Mockingbird](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Barbara_Morse_(Earth-616))
19. [Crossbones](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Brock_Rumlow_(Earth-616))
20. [Ronan the Accuser](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Ronan_(Earth-616))
21. [Spider-Woman (Jessica Drew)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Jessica_Drew_(Earth-616))
22. [Spider-Man 2099](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Miguel_O%27Hara_(Earth-928))
23. [Billy Connors](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/William_Connors_(Earth-616))
24. [Doctor Octopus](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Otto_Octavius_(Earth-616))
25. [The Mandarin](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mandarin_(Earth-616))
26. [Baron Strucker](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Wolfgang_von_Strucker_(Earth-616))
27. [The White Tiger (Ava Ayala)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Ava_Ayala_(Earth-616))
28. [Medusa](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Medusalith_Amaquelin_(Earth-616))
29. [Triton](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Triton_(Earth-616))
30. [Karnak](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Karnak_Mander-Azur_(Earth-616))
31. [Gorgon](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Gorgon_Petragon_(Earth-616))
32. [Ms. America](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/America_Chavez_(Utopian_Parallel))
33. [Crystal](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Crystalia_Amaquelin_(Earth-616))
34. [Quake](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Daisy_Johnson_(Earth-616))
35. [The Kingpin](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Wilson_Fisk_(Earth-616))
36. [Deathlok (Henry Hayes)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Henry_Hayes_(Earth-616))
37. [Sharon Carter](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Sharon_Carter_(Earth-616))
38. [Madame Masque](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Giuletta_Nefaria_(Earth-616))
39. [Taskmaster](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Tony_Masters_(Earth-616))
40. [Malekith](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Malekith_(Earth-616))
41. [Odin](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Odin_Borson_(Earth-616))
42. [Volstagg](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Volstagg_(Earth-616))
43. [Hogun](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Hogun_(Earth-616))
44. [Heimdall](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Heimdall_(Earth-616))
45. [Sif](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Sif_(Earth-616))
46. [Fandral](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Fandral_(Earth-616))
47. [Laufey](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Laufey_(Earth-616))
48. [Black Bolt](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Blackagar_Boltagon_(Earth-616))
49. [The Punisher](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Frank_Castle_(Earth-616))
50. [Thanos](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thanos_(Earth-616))
51. [Agent Venom (Flash Thompson)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Eugene_Thompson_(Earth-616))
52. [Moon Knight](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marc_Spector_(Earth-616))
53. [Ultron](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Ultron_(Earth-616))
54. [The Falcon](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Samuel_Wilson_(Earth-616))
55. [A.I.M. agents](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Advanced_Idea_Mechanics_(Earth-616))
56. [Ms. Marvel (Kamala Khan)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Kamala_Khan_(Earth-616))
57. [She-Hulk](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Jennifer_Walters_(Earth-616))
58. [Ghost Rider](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Johnathon_Blaze_(Earth-616))
59. [Skaar](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Skaar_(Earth-616))
60. [The Leader](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Samuel_Sterns_(Earth-616))
61. [The Vision](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Vision_(Earth-616))
62. [Loki](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Loki_Laufeyson_(Earth-616))
63. [Red Hulk](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thaddeus_Ross_(Earth-616))
64. [A-Bomb](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Richard_Jones_(Earth-616))
65. [Balder](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Balder_Odinson_(Earth-616))
66. [Gamora](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Gamora_Zen_Whoberi_Ben_Titan_(Earth-7528))
67. [Daredevil](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Matthew_Murdock_(Earth-616))
68. [Captain Marvel (Carol Danvers)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Carol_Danvers_(Earth-616))
69. [Iron Fist](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Daniel_Rand_(Earth-616))
70. [Nick Fury Jr.](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Nicholas_Fury,_Jr._(Earth-616))
71. [Elektra](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Elektra_Natchios_(Earth-616))
72. [Jessica Jones](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Jessica_Jones_(Earth-616))
73. [Star-Lord](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Quill_(Earth-616))
74. [The Red Skull](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Johann_Shmidt_(Earth-616))
75. [Luke Cage](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Luke_Cage_(Earth-616))
76. [Maria Hill](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Maria_Hill_(Earth-616))
77. [The Hulk](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Bruce_Banner_(Earth-616))
78. [Black Widow](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Natalia_Romanova_(Earth-616))
79. [Doctor Strange](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Stephen_Strange_(Earth-616))
80. [Winter Soldier](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/James_Buchanan_Barnes_(Earth-616))
81. [Chitauri alien](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Chitauri)
82. [Drax](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Arthur_Douglas_(Earth-616))
83. [Bullseye](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Bullseye_(Lester)_(Earth-616))
84. [The Black Panther](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/T%27Challa_(Earth-616))
85. [Lockjaw](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Lockjaw_(Earth-616))
86. [Spider-Man (Peter Parker)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-616))
87. [Captain America](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Steven_Rogers_(Earth-616))
88. [Iron Man](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Anthony_Stark_(Earth-616))
89. [Thor](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor_Odinson_(Earth-616))
90. [The Wasp](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Janet_Van_Dyne_(Earth-616))
91. [Hawkeye](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Clinton_Barton_(Earth-616))
92. [Ant-Man](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Henry_Pym_(Earth-616))
93. [Spider-Man (Miles Morales)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Miles_Morales_(Earth-1610))
94. [Groot](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Groot_(Earth-616))
95. [Cosmo](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Cosmo_(Dog)_(Earth-616))
96. [Rocket Raccoon](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Rocket_Raccoon_(Earth-616))

Comment: Regarding character #23, whom I've identified as Billy Connors (son of Curt Connors, the Lizard), I imagine the makers of this puzzle intended to use an image of his father, but that is actually an image of Billy, taken from _[Sensational Spider-Man Vol 2 #24](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Sensational_Spider-Man_Vol_2_24)_.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Numbered list of characters]

1. ? *(Man with ball & chain)*
2. ? Green Goblin
3. ? *(Man in green outfit)*
4. ? *(Man in green outfit with purple mask and belt)*
5. ? *(Man with blonde hair and red mask)*
6. ? Juggernaut *(Silhouette character with domed head)*
7. Arnim Zola
8. ? *(Man with purple face and blue tie)*
9. ? *(Asian man in green/grey armour)*
10. Warmachine
11. ? *(Man with skull on chest)*
12. Venom
13. MODOK
14. Devil Dinosaur
15. ? *(Flying character)*
16. Ego
17. ? *(Man with purple mask)*
18. ? *(Blonde woman in green & black)*
19. ? *(Man with skull mask)*
20. ? *(Blue man with green armour)*
21. ? *(Woman in red and black)*
22. ? *(Blue and red character)*
23. ? The Lizard /  Dr. Curtis Connors
24. Dr. Octopus / Dr. Otto Gunther Octavius
25. ? *(Man in green robe)*
26. ? *(Bald man in green outfit)*
27. ? *(Woman with black hair and white and black outfit holding a gun)*
28. Dr. Victor Von Doom
29. ? White Tiger
30. ? *(man in light blue armour)*
31. ? Lady Sif *(Woman with red winged helm and sword)*
32. ? Laufey *(Possible Frost Giant?)*
33. ? *(Woman in stars and stripes)*
34. ? *(Close cropped hair, bionic arm)*
35. ? *(Man with red suit, red visor and weapon on shoulder)*
36. ? *(Woman in white)*
37. ? *(White hair, black and white face, purple outfit)*
38. ? *(Horned helm, long beard, possibly one of the Asgardian "Warriors Three")*
39. ? *(Purple outfit, M on the belt)*
40. ? *(Green person)*
41. ? *(Man with green gem on hat)*
42. ? *(Naked woman - maybe the Invisible Woman)*
43. The Kingpin
44. ? The Destroyer *(Black & orange robot)*
45. ? *(Orange biohazard Suit)*
46. Ms. Marvel / Kamala Khan
47. ? *(Long red beard, holding a mace, possibly one of the Asgardian "Warriors Three")*
48. ? *(Man in green tunic holding a sword, possibly the final Asgardian "Warrior Three")*
49. ? *(Man in black body suit with white zig-zags)*
50. ? *(Man holding gun with sniper scope, possibly The Punisher)*
51. ? *(Man with open mouth wearing headpiece and cloak holding an electrified mace)*
52. ? *(Person with black face and white outfit)*
53. ? *(Orange biohazard Suit)*
54. Ghostrider
55. Leader / Sam Sterns
56. Vision
57. ? *(Red man)*
58. ? *(Man in armour with white cloak and red tabard)*
59. Thanos
60. ? *(Blue outfit with a spider on the chest)*
61. Falcon / Samuel Wilson
62. ? *(Green Woman - maybe She Hulk or Gamora)*
63. ? *(Green man)*
64. Loki
65. ? *(Blue person, maybe the Thing)*
66. ? *(Green Woman - maybe She Hulk or Gamora)*
67. Captain Marvel
68. Electra
69. The Red Skull
70. ? Maria Hill (Woman with dark hair and possibly Shield logo)
71. The Hulk / Bruce Banner
72. Black Widow / Natasha Romanoff
73. Dr. Stephen Strange
74. ? *(Skeletal figure with pike)*
75. Bullseye
76. The Winter Soldier / Bucky Barnes
77. ? *(Green man with red stripes on the shoulders, maybe Drax)*
78. ? *(Man with beard and white T-shirt)*
79. Daredevil
80. Iron Fist
81. Nick Fury
82. Scarlet Witch / Wanda Maximoff
83. Star-Lord / Peter Quill
84. Iron Man / Tony Stark
85. Thor
86. Hawkeye
87. Groot
88. Black Panther
89. Captain America / Steve Rogers
90. Antman / Scott Lang
91. Miles Morales
92. Rocket
93. Spiderman / Peter Parker
94. Lockjaw
95. The Wasp / Hope van Dyne
96. Cosmo the Spacedog
97. ? *(Man in hat with blue outfit)*

There are lots that I don't know or am unsure of. I made this a community wiki so people can fill in the unknowns.